# How to refresh the same activity with new text when button is pressed

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity  in foreground. 
when i press a button "OK" on the activity, the same activity must come on top with new fields in it.

I changed the button text from OK to CANCEL in onclick handler. It worked fine.
But user cant see that that a new page is loaded .

I am new to android, can someone hint me?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

But as a quick start you should [build a new intent](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent) to start your `Activity`. You can pass data between your `Activities` using `putExtra` methods on your `Intent`:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityName.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

When you start your `Activity` you can [retrieve the data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#ReceiveIntent) stored inside the `Intent` using the following:

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

You can then [display the message](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#DisplayMessage) (or any other data field) inside your `View`:

```
textView.setText(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work? (Place it in your onClick method)

```
TextView txtView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView1.setText(newText)
```

where newText is the new String that you need to place in textView and R.id.textView1 is the reference to your TextView in your layout.